# mobx + react unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

so i created an app with react without configuration from https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html

I installed mobx and mobx-react ,but is still shows the error of unexpected token before @ symb.

Do I need to add something else, or my current configuration is wrong ?:(

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
"react-scripts": "0.8.4",
"babel-core": "^6.7.6",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"autobind-decorator": "^1.3.4",
"classnames": "^2.2.5",
"lodash": "^4.15.0",
"mobx": "^2.5.1",
"mobx-react": "^3.5.5",
"react": "^15.3.1",
"react-dom": "^15.3.1",
"validator": "^5.6.0"
 },
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": [
      "transform-decorators-legacy",
      "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}
```

And the code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { action, observable } from 'mobx'
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';


class App {
    @observer cake = [];
}

export default new App();
```

Comment: `@observer` is the decorator used for your React components. If you want observable data, you should use the decorator `@observable`.

Comment: Whatever i use, when i use @ symb it stops right there. So I think that mobx is not installed properly

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood. I think it is because create-react-app does not support decorators (`@`) at all. I don't think MobX is the culprit here. You could try the [**mobx-react-boilerplate**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-boilerplate) instead.

Comment: thanks, i will try it out ;)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[**create-react-app**](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html) does not support decorators (`@`). You could either [**eject**](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html#no-lock-in) create-react-app to add it yourself, set up your own environment from scratch, or use something like [**mobx-react-boilerplate**](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react-boilerplate) as your starting point.

I have personally used [**react-app-rewired**](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) with the [**mobx extension**](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired/tree/master/packages/react-app-rewire-mobx) with great success.

Comment: I built a starter kit with CRNA that if used with nodejs 6.0 works perfectly with decorator, the project documentation for it is available at https://wcandillon.github.io/react-native-do-documentation/docs/

Answer (score 9):

You are missing packages after running [npm run eject](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html#no-lock-in) (as create-react-app does not support decorators).

Run `npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`

Then add the following Babel configuration to your package.json

```
"babel": {
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ],
  "presets": [
    "react-app"
  ]
},
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to add `transform-class-properties` to the Babel plugins array as well.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the syntax provided that doesn't use decorators ([here](https://mobx.js.org/best/decorators.html) and [here](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/extend-observable.html)).

Here's an example using the App class code you provided:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { action, extendObservable } from 'mobx'
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';


class App {
  constructor() {
    extendObservable(this, {
      cake = [],
    }); 
  }
}

export default new App();
```